# Why User id not enter in sequence?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The problem is, User id enter randomly, or not enter in sequence like this:

[image: Firebase-screenshot]

*problem description*

The last entry is `"bill"` why is `"Warren"` shifted to number three? This shift makes my bar chart not sequential on the x Axis.

What I want is `"Warren"` to stay in second place and `"bill"` must be under the `"Warren"`.

*this is my code:*

```
...

DatabaseReference reference = db.getReference("Attendance")

reference.child(uid).setValue(new CurrentAttandance(cA, userCount, xname));
```

any help thank you guys. :-)

Comment: I'm a noob in Firebase, never used it. But I believe it is sorted by the randomized string that is visible in your image. Thus, not making it sequential. The big question is, why does it have to be sequential?

Comment: thank you for the edit. my graph should be squent.. i have no idea. @J.A.P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "random" user ID you're stating is not appearing automatically or it is not just any random bunch of String characters. It looks like the `uid` of the user.

Please add the code, but from the output I am guessing that you're adding your users in the database, with code that looks something like this:

```java
ref.child(mAuth.getUid()).child("xname").setValue(name);
```

This is the reason that the Strings are appearing as the parent child in your Firebase database.

Also as @J.A.P correctly pointed in the comment, the order is according to the lexicographic nature of the parent Strings that are `uid` of the user in your database.

If you want them to be ordered according to order by which they sign up, then add a `timestamp` in your Firebase Database as sibling child of `xname` and show the list in order of your `timestamp`.